# Blackberry download failure

Tags: blackberry, download

I'm developing for Blackberry OS 5.

When I tried to use `Browser` to download a file from the internet through my app, the loading takes too long and failed. Anyone know why?

```java
int clearConfirm = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO,
                              "Do you want to download?",
                              Dialog.NO);

if (clearConfirm == Dialog.YES) {
    try {
        Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://mysite/blackberry/file.cod");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is my code ... what's wrong?

Comment: are you using wifi, or the carrier network, for this download?  how big is your .cod file?  can you enter the same URL into the standalone Browser app (not using your code) and download the file successfully?

Comment: i using lan connection. cod file only 6kb.
the download succesfully from standalone browser, but it should OS 7
any ideas or another code?

Comment: try surrounding the call to `displayPage()` with a `try {} catch {}` block, and see if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: could you mind writting the code implementation within my code above because i don't understand how to use try {} catch {}

Comment: I edited the code to catch exceptions.  Put a breakpoint on this line: `e.printStackTrace()`, or watch the console window for output when you request the page.

Comment: ok thanks, wait a moment. i'll try it.

Comment: nothing change
this is the error message when the connection has failed
"unable to connect to the selected Mobile Data Service, please try again later.
if the problem persists please contact your administrator."

Comment: You need request jad file instead of cod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deployment/Installation steps in device (Simulating the blackberry Appworld environment):**

- Create a blackberry folder in your server and paste the xxx.cod and xxx.jad in server. extract the .cod file using zip extractor. (To do this, first rename the .cod to .zip, and then extract at the same folder).
- Make sure your server is accessible from the mobile.

Note: If the server is deployed in a private IP (LAN) then, Wi-Fi connection is required in mobile to access the server. If it is deployed over a public IP, then we can access using any of the network Wi-Fi, 2G or 2G or other network operators APN settings connections.

- In your above code change the url to

> Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://mysite/blackberry/file.jad");

Browser will download and install the jad file and then internally all other files. Restart the device, if required.

This works for me. It should work for you too.

**Edit-1**

The above issue may be due to size of the cod file. But my solution will be best fit for it.